# limit the output of a list to two items

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I limit the output that goes into the li tag to the last two items?  Here's what I have so far:

```
{% regroup backups by dataset as dataset_list %}
{% for dataset in dataset_list %}

<h2>{{ dataset.grouper }}</h2>

<ul>
     {% for item in dataset.list %}
        <li>
            {% if item.state = "FAILED" %}<span class="icon-cross red"> {{ item.snapshot_name }} took {{ item.start_time|timesince:item.stop_time }} to transfer {{ item.transfer_size }} and <span class="red">{{ item.state }}</span>
     {% else %}
     <span class="icon-tick green"> {{ item.snapshot_name }} took {{ item.start_time|timesince:item.stop_time }} to transfer {{ item.transfer_size }}
            {% endif %}
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Which generates the output that looks like this:

```
pool-test/data

    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-06-0647 took 2 hours, 43 minutes to transfer 249GB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-13-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 29.6KB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-20-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 3.23KB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-27-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 312B
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-02-03-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 312B

pool-test2/data

    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2012-12-16-0647 took 13 minutes to transfer 35.9GB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2012-12-23-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 6.16MB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-06-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 22.4MB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-13-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 20.7MB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-20-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 19.1MB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-27-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 17.7MB
    zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-02-03-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 10.2MB
```

I'd like it to end up looking like:

```
    pool-test/data

        zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-27-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 312B
        zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-02-03-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 312B

    pool-test2/data

        zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-01-27-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 17.7MB
        zfs-auto-snap_weekly-2013-02-03-0647 took 0 minutes to transfer 10.2MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [slice filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice):

`{% for item in dataset.list|slice:"-2:" %}`

Comment: Is there a guaranteed sort order for regroup?

Comment: `regroup` doesn't sort, it just groups consecutive matching objects together. The order will remain how it was.

Comment: @erinmar77, make sure you are sorting by the field you desire when creating dataset and do not rely on the sort order that is coming out naturally. Thanks.